# SignalR SQL Server Broker - Orphaned Service Broker Queue Errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, signalr, service-broker, signalr-backplane

I am using SQL Server Broker on SQL Server 2008 for Scaleout with SignalR v2.1.2.  It was recently discovered that we are producing 50k+ errors per day in our DB logs.  After some research, there are 3 orphaned Service Broker queues from December.  Error example:

2016-02-27 23:58:01.79 spid30s     The activated proc '[dbo].[SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-2ffbddba-6ddc-4ad0-88b4-45a405e975e0]' running on queue 'MY_SIGNALR_DB.dbo.SqlQueryNotificationService-2ffbddba-6ddc-4ad0-88b4-45a405e975e0' output the following:  'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-2ffbddba-6ddc-4ad0-88b4-45a405e975e0'.'

These queues were created in December and were NOT dropped for some reason.  The corresponding SPs were apparently dropped as expected.  The DB will produce an error every 5 seconds for this (equates to 50k per day with 3 queues).  Each queue DOES contain a message.

Questions:

What can cause this?

Are there additional SignalR settings that can be implemented to ensure these are cleaned up?

Is this a bug in SQL Server Service Broker?

Is there a document which describes SignalR's expected behavior with regards to Queues and their expiration?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

These are leftover from [`SqlDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx). The implementation of the [`SqlDependency.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224871(v=vs.110).aspx) is to create a just-in-time service, queue and activated procedure (see the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDependency.cs,499c269b4b628488)). This has some [issues](http://rusanu.com/2007/11/10/when-it-rains-it-pours/), and even a simple Visual Studio [debugging](http://rusanu.com/2008/01/04/sqldependencyonchange-callback-timing/) session can leave stranded queues/activated procedures.

You can clean up these left-over service/queue/procedures as they happen, or you can choose to use the lower level [`SqlNotificationRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqlnotificationrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class and handle the service/queue deployment on your own. Pick your poison.